# Interactive shell through named pipe

Tags: bash, pipe

Can I create a named pipe, and then use that as an interactive shell? So far I've tried `/bin/sh 0<p 1>p` (where `p` is my pipe), and it allows me to execute commands by echoing them into `p`, but I would like to get the output to the console I execute it on.

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310)? What is your goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible but only with two pipes (otherwise the shell reads the own stdout on stdin).

```bsh
mkfifo p0 p1
bash 0<p0 1>p1
```

```bsh
cat p1 &
cat > p0
echo ok
ok
```

Comment: I don't get any output when I type 'echo ok'; or any other commands. Edit: Fixed, you used `p2` when it should have been `p0`

Comment: Yes indeed. I called the pipes a and b for the quick test before posting and messes up then because I wanted to stay closer to Your p. Sorry for the typo and thanks for reviewing.